# Concur / Cognos Report Studio - Create Report of Travel Destination Countries

Tags: report, cognos, cognos-bi, sap-concur

this question is very specific to the Concur implementation of the IBM Cognos Report Studio tool since it primarily focuses on the data model used therein.
It contains business travel expense information including the travel itineraries, which are the main source of this report:
[Itinerary Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFGLW.gif)

My goal now is to create a report showing which destination countries the employees traveled to (all countries if more than one country was visited in a single itinerary), how many single business trips were taken to that destination country/countries, the average duration of the business trips to that destination country/countries and the number of all trips. If possible, duration of stay by country would be great, but i have no idea how to go about that. [Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysK1K.gif)

Using a repeater based on the field [Arrival Country] from the itinerary, i managed to get something that looks what i am trying to achieve, but it somehow does not include the home country once i cut out the other identifying columns (Itinerary Key, Departure Country, Arrival Country).
I then did a count(distinct([Itinerary Key] for [Arrival Country Repeater] which gave me numbers, but i am not really sure they are correct in this case.
[Repeater](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNYAP.gif)

Also, as soon as i add query calculations to include the average duration, the repeater fields go blank.

Is there another way to get the report i want to build?
Are there major flaws with my attempt?

Thanks a ton for any and all suggestions!

Comment: It would be very difficult to give you guidance using just the information provided. Ideally, you would include a screenshot of the current state and a mock-up of what you want it to look like and any other relevant information.

Comment: Hi Johnsonium, thanks for the response and sorry it took me so long to edit my question - the joys of not having access to image hosting sites. What other information would be needed to estimate whether it is possible to create such a report? (i noticed there does not seem to be a standard report for this, even though it seems not that far-fetched to me to want to report on the countries employees travel to...)